# rspec controller spec accessing route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a location resource and access via:

```
http://localhost:3000/locations/37/edit
```

In my spec, I have:

```
it "should allows us to edit" do
  @u=User.find_by_email('jon@domain.com')
  session[:user_id]=@u.id    
  get edit_location_path, {:id => '37'}
```

but get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) LocationsController should allows us to edit
     Failure/Error: get edit_location_path, :id => '37'
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"locations"}
     # ./spec/controllers/locations_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How would I specify the link to this resource?

thx

Comment: It looks like you're loosing the `id` in your route, it's not showing up in the route error (there should be a `:id => '37'` in there).

Comment: You might want to mock the Location model, and pass that to edit_location_path(location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `get edit_location_path(37)` ??

Comment: thx, I had a syntax error on the response that was causing problem

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a controller spec describing `LocationsController`, you can access it with `get :edit, :id => 37`.